# Can Grails app contain REST client and server at the same time?

Tags: rest, grails, rest-client, grails-2.3

I am trying to see if the built-in REST functionality that Grails ships with will allow the same Grails app to hit a RESTful API endpoint on another machine (effectively making it the REST client), as well as serving that same API endpoint so that it can be hit from other machines (effectively making it the REST server).

For instance, say I have 2 Grails apps, App A and App B. Both will expose a `/ping` REST endpoint, that, perhaps, returns a JSON "pong" message when hit from an HTTP GET. I am wondering if App A can hit App B's `/ping` endpoint, while also serving an endpoint of the same name/signature (so that App B can hit App A's `/ping` as well)?

**Most importantly**, going one step further, I'd like to abstract both RESTful client/server functionality (for `/ping`) out into a Grails plugin, say `grails-pingrest.zip`, and then have both Apps A and B import this plugin as a dependency. That way both share the same codebase for client & server implementations.

Is this possible? If so, how and are there any obstacles/caveats/gotchyas. If not, why?

Comment: Entirely possible for this to happen. Using a plugin is the correct approach as well.

Comment: Thanks @JoshuaMoore (+1) - I am concerned however about port interference or just general communication issues if the same Grails app is listening on Port 8080 and serving `/ping` requests, as well as making requests to another machine's `/ping` endpoint. Any thoughts on this type of interference?

Comment: There won't be any interference at all. No reason at all as to why there would be.

Comment: Thanks @JoshuaMoore (+1) - but what if App A sends an outbound `/ping` HTTP GET to App B at the same time that App B does the same to App A? Couldn't there be contention on the port?

Comment: Nope, since requests are served in different threads. Even if you host the two applications on the same server they are going to be served by different threads and are still different applications. Even if they use the same plugin internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are definitely on the right path with creating a plugin with this shared functionality. You won't have any issues calling out to the same endpoint but on a different application even if the same application has the same endpoint.

someplace.com/ping and myotherplace.com/ping won't have any issues nor would domain.com/appa/ping and domain.com/appb/ping